# Typescript: Serialize interface types to array of classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, game-engine

I have problem with typescript typings.

Currently, I am working on small game engine, which uses entity-component-system model. I want to "serialize" types of interface into the array of classes (a types of each interface property) to inform system about needed components.

What I want to achieve ideally:

```js
export interface IMovable {
    position: CompPosition;
    velocity: CompVelocity;
}

export class MoveSystem extends System<IMovable> {

    // This array should have type, to ensure all components classes from IMovable are listed.
    protected requiredComponents = [ CompPosition, CompVelocity ];

    /// ...

}
```

What I want to do at least:

```js
export interface IMovable {
    position: CompPosition;
    velocity: CompVelocity;
}

export class MoveSystem extends System<IMovable> {

    /* The properties of requiredComponents have the same name as in interface, but their types are 
       different - in interface, the type requires instances (which I want to keep this way in the 
       interface), but requiredComponents should contain classes. */
    protected requiredComponents = {
        position: CompPosition, 
        velocity: CompVelocity 
    };

    /// ...

}
```

Thanks for every suggestion.

Comment: Do you want to have a tuple of size 2 or an array that can take as many of either interface as needed?

Comment: @voiys As many as interface have. There can be interface with n number of components.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Michael The game engine needs to know, which components are needed in entity, to assing entity to specific system(s). Interface is just union of these components. When system is doing operations above entities, then interface will provide them type information of available components.

Comment: Ok, one thing that is important to understand about typescript is that the type system is at build time only - at runtime interfaces do not exist. It sounds a little like you're trying to do dependency injection. I'd suggest constructor injection as being a good option here.

Comment: @Michael Right, I know that, but that's not my problem here - most likely I did not explained it well. What I need is just a type, which will "instruct" programmer (creator of specific ECS system) to insert all required components into an array `requiredComponents`. The game engine will then be processing only the array of component classes (where their ID is stored). The interface is only for programmer (and IDE) to give them info about components present in entity. (ei. Player entity has components MoveComp, VelocityComp, RenderComp...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found solution. Not the best one possible, but it works the way it should:

```js
type Class<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

type ComponentStore<T> = { [P in keyof T]: Component };
type RequiredComponents<T extends ComponentStore<T>> = { [P in keyof T]: Class<T[P]> };

abstract class System<T extends ComponentStore<T>> {

    protected abstract requiredComponents: RequiredComponents<T>;

    // ...

}

interface IMovable {
    position: CompPosition;
    velocity: CompVelocity;
}

class MoveSystem extends System<IMovable> {

    protected requiredComponents = {
        position: CompPosition,
        velocity: CompVelocity
    };

    // ...

}
```

**But thanks everyone, who tried or even read it.**

Answer (score 0):

So this is the best I can come up with. I don't believe this is possible to do (and if so not ergonomically from a developer perspective) with the array approach, so I've gone for the object one.

```
class Position implements Component {
    x: number = 0
    y: number = 0
    readonly requiredComponents: {}
}

class Velocity implements Component {
    velX: number = 0
    velY: number = 0
    readonly requiredComponents: {}
}

type ComponentConstructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T

interface Component<A = {}, B = {}, C = {}, D = {}> {
    readonly requiredComponents: A & B & C & D
}

interface IMovable {
    position: ComponentConstructor<Position>
    velocity: ComponentConstructor<Velocity>
}

class Player implements Component<IMovable> {
    readonly requiredComponents = {
        position: Position,
        velocity: Velocity,
    }
}
```

With a bit more context on how these components will work / interact I feel like I could possibly provide a better solution - I'm not convinced what you're trying to do is necessary still.